I keep getting a deadlock error any time i attempt to make an api call in golang compiled to wasm
As the title describes i am trying to make an api call in golang that is compiled to wasm it works fine when it is run on a machine but returns a deadlock error all go routines asleep whenever i run it in the browser. Thanks.
func APIcall(url string) map[string]interface{} {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    var body string
    for {
        n, err := resp.Body.Read(buffer)
        if err == io.EOF {
            // Reached the end of the body
            body += string(buffer[:n])
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading response:", err)
        }
        body += string(buffer[:n])
    }

    var result map[string]interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    results, ok := result["results"].([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Error:", "Could not cast 'results' to a slice of interfaces")
    }

    if len(results) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No results found in the response")
    }

    result = results[0].(map[string]interface{})
    return result
}

I expect for a map to be returned but instead all i get are deadlock errors.

I am not a wasm expert but things like http requests eg. open connections is a thing that is not possible in wasm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102612/is-it-possible-to-submit-http-requests-with-webassembly
